# Yii2 ActiveForm submit

Tags: php, javascript, yii2, yii, form

У меня есть 2 формы одна обычная

```
 <form id="payment" name="payment" method="post" action="https://sci.interkassa.com/" enctype="utf-8"
          target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_co_id" value="hdjfhjsdjsdhkj7833jfjsdhf"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_pm_no" value="ID_<?= rand(1000, 9999) ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_am" value="<?= $game->price ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_cur" value="UAH"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_desc" value="<?= $game->name ?>"/>
    </form>
```

и одна ActiveForm

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
            <div class="buymail"><?= $form->field($model, 'email')->input('email')->label("E-mail *") ?></div><div class="checkaccept">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'accept')
                    ->checkbox([
                        'label' => 'Я ознакомлен с пользовательским соглашением и описанием товара*',
                    ]) ?></div>  
            <div class="buybtn"><?= Html::submitButton('Перейти к оплате  →', ['class' => 'asbtn subbtnbuy', 'onclick' => 'submitform()', 'disabled' => true]) ?></div>  
    <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Мне нужно както сделать так чтобы 1 обычная форма отправлялась после успешного заполнения 2 формы и нажатия на ее submit, сначало сделал так в js допсал

```
function submitform() {
    document.payment.submit(); }
```

а на submit повесил обработчик `onclick' => 'submitform()'`, но так 1 форма отправляется при любом нажатии на submit независимо от того прошла ли валидацию 2-я форма, потом сделал так установил атрибут submit 'disabled' => true, а в js написал так

```
var regex = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

$('#buy-accept').change(function(){
if(regex.test($('#buy-email').val())){
    $(".subbtnbuy").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
} });
```

то есть кнопка будет неактивной пока пользователь не заполнит поля 2 формы а именно email и чекбокс, в принципе оно то и работает так как нужно но при этом никаких сообщений про незаполненные поля выдаваться не будет, да и потом если галочку поставить раньше чем заполнить поле с почтой придется ее опять снимать и ставить чтоб разблокировать кнопку submit. Вот такой вопрос можно как то к сабмиту одной формы прикрепить передачу допустим в новое окно другой формы, при этом чтобы передача 2 формы срабатывала после правильного заполнения первой, или как это можно сделать иначе чтобы передавалось 2 формы по нажатию на 1 submit, но после валидации полей той формы в которой указан submit?

Comment: Как по поводу поля из формы №1 поместить внутрь формы №2, в итоге все заработает без танцев с бубном и без лишнего POST-a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, вкл/выкл кнопки - это самое простое решение. Но правильным было бы сделать валидацию и при клике на submit первой формы проверять валидность данных второй. Например переделать функцию `submitform`:

```js
var validateAlgoritm = {
   email: {
      rule: function (email) {
      
        return /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/.test(email);
     },
     errorText: 'Ваш e-mail не прошел валидацию'
   }
   
},
$email = $('#buy-email');

function validateForm2() {
    var result = {
       status: true,
       text: 'ok'
    };
   if(!validateAlgoritm.email.rule($email.val())) {
     result.status = false;
     result.text = validateAlgoritm.email.errorText;
   }
   
   return result;
};


function submitForm() {
    var valid = validateForm2();
    if(valid.status) {
      document.payment.submit();
    } else {
       alert(valid.text);
    }
     
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="email" id="buy-email">
<form id="payment" name="payment" method="post"  action="https://sci.interkassa.com/" enctype="utf-8"
          target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_co_id" value="hdjfhjsdjsdhkj7833jfjsdhf"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_pm_no" value="ID_<?= rand(1000, 9999) ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_am" value="<?= $game->price ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_cur" value="UAH"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="ik_desc" value="<?= $game->name ?>"/>
        <input type="button" value="send" onclick="submitForm()">
    </form>
```